# Tableview with pagecontroll

Tags: ios, swift

I want to build an app with tableview and Limit results to size of the screen, no vertical scrolling Sliding left takes to next page of results and sliding right takes to previous page of results (of the same search), dashes at the bottom shows the page position. Refer image.

[image]

Comment: You'd get more answers if you posted some code about your trials so far and explain where you have issues.

Comment: If you are not going to make use of a tableView's built-in scrolling and cell reuse, you may be (probably ***will be***) better off using custom views (in stack views to make it easier). Or... use a collection view with horizontal flow layout...

Comment: I'm using cell reuse,  It will be very help full if you give some code

Comment: Use a horizontal scrolling Collection view and add tableview in collectionviewcell. Split the array by 5 objects per one tableview

Comment: @saras - are your "rows" all the same, fixed height? Or might each row be a different / dynamic height? That is, might only 3 rows fit on your first "page" but 5 rows fit on the next page, 4 rows on the next, and so on?